# Converting raster to integer values and exporting as 16 bit using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion, command-line, integer

I am trying to export a DEM raster as a 16 bit image using the Raster>Conversion>Translate drop down menus in QGIS.  I have seen somewhere I need to save it with a -ot tag to turn it into a 16 bit image but I cannot work out how to do that.  If I type in -ot into the end of the output file name it does not work . I know I am not getting it.

Alternatively, how do I do it via command line?

Comment: The Translate tool that you are using has a drop down menu for "Output data type". The default is "Use Input Layer Data Type" but you want to select "Int16".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, simply select the data type from the dropdown list:

[image: screenshot]